# Hashtag posted via feed dialog not appearing in hashtag search in Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, hashtag

I created a Feed Dialog to share my content from my website to Facebook.

I used a hashtag before sharing it to Facebook.

The content was posted in my timeline, but when i searched using the hashtag I used, the post did not appear in the search result of Facebook for that hashtag.

Comment: What's the request you're making to search by hashtags? Are you using the Topic Feed API documented on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#search

Comment: got this solved, FB doesn't include the hashtag posted externally